# Phonegap. Null value being inserted into database table. Datatype conflict?

Tags: javascript, cordova

I have an issue with the following piece of code.

I have a form where users can select from a dropdown of existing locations and games, or if it doesn't exist, they can select "add a new game/location" and enter the name of the game and or location in a text field. When they do this, I want to write the new game and/or location to the database, and get the newly created ID so I can correctly update my sessions table (where game sessions are recorded).

The new locations and games are being written correctly, however, when I add a new one I end up with a null value in the game and location fields of the sessions table.

The commented out alerts when inserting the new games and locations are returning the correct value.

```
function addSession(tx){
  var locationID = $('#location').val();
  var gameID = $('#game').val();
  if ($('#location').val() == '0'){
    tx.executeSql(
      'INSERT INTO locations (lTitle) VALUES (?)',
      [$('#newLocation').val()],
      function(tx, results){
        locationID = results.insertId;
      },
      errorCB
    );
  }
  if ($('#game').val() == '0'){
    tx.executeSql(
      'INSERT INTO games (lTitle) VALUES (?)',
      [$('#newGame').val()],
      function(tx, results){
        gameID = results.insertId;
      },
      errorCB
    );
  }
  var sSQL = 'INSERT INTO sessions (date, duration, location, game, notes) VALUES '
    + '("'+$('#date').val()+' '+$('#time').val()+':00.000"'
    +',2.5,'+locationID+','+gameID+',"'+$('#notes').val()+'")';
  tx.executeSql(
    sSQL,
    [],
    function(tx,results){
      //todo after successful entry
    },
    errorCB
  );
}
```

I initially thought it may be because the insert into the sessions table was executing before the inserts into the game and location tables, but if this was the case I would be getting '0' entered into the game and location fields instead of null.

When I add a new session using an existing item from the game or location menus (ID's will be >0), the insert works fine.

Here is the setup of the sessions table incase it may be related to a datatype conflict. I have tried parseInt on the returned ID's but that has the same result

```
tx.executeSql(
  'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sessions ' +
  '(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , ' +
  'date TEXT, ' +
  'duration REAL, ' +
  'game INTEGER, ' +
  'location INTEGER, ' +
  'notes TEXT' +
  ')'
);
```

Comment: What is this `tx` thing and why does it appear to be running SQL queries on the client-side?

Comment: It is a local database: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that this was due to the execution of the various queries in the wrong order.

I managed to sort this by separating the functions like so:

```
//FUNCTION TO ADD NEW LOCATIONS
function addLocation(tx){
    tx.executeSql(
        'INSERT INTO locations (lTitle) VALUES (?)',
        [$('#newLocation').val()],
        function(tx, results){
            locationID = results.insertId;
        },
        errorCB
    );
}

//FUNCTION TO ADD NEW GAMES
function addGame(tx){
    tx.executeSql(
        'INSERT INTO games (gTitle) VALUES (?)',
        [$('#newGame').val()],
        function(tx, results){
            gameID = results.insertId;
        },
        errorCB
    );
}

//FUNCTION TO ADD NEW SESSION
function addSessionGo(tx){
    var sSQL = 'INSERT INTO sessions (date, game, location, notes) VALUES ' +
        '("'+$('#date').val()+' '+$('#time').val()+':00.000"' +
        ','+gameID+','+locationID+',"'+$('#notes').val()+'")';
    //alert(sSQL);

    tx.executeSql(
        sSQL,
        [],
        function(tx,results){
            //todo after successful entry
            //alert('Added new session');
        },
        errorCB
    );
}


//FUNCTION TO START ADDING THE NEW SESSION
function addSession(tx){
    locationID = $('#location').val();
    gameID = $('#game').val();

    if ($('#location').val() == '0'){
        db.transaction(addLocation, errorCB);
    }

    if ($('#game').val() == '0'){
        db.transaction(addGame, errorCB);
    }

    db.transaction(addSessionGo, errorCB);
}
```